# jQuery Animate/Offset problem

Tags: jquery, position, offset

I have a little scheme of chairs. When I hover over the chair, I get a little popup made with jQuery. The position of the pop-up is based on the `offset()` of the chair I hover over.

When I scroll, though, the popup remains on the same place in the DOCUMENT, but instead it should be aligned to the chair I hover over.

[Here's an example](http://www.times-lan.nl/?page=event/seatplan.test).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sp_seat").live('mouseover', function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var x = $(this).offset().left;
        var y = $(this).offset().top;

        $('#seat_'+id).css({"left":(x+30)+"px","top":(y+10)+"px"});

        $('#seat_'+id).fadeIn('fast');

    });

    $(".sp_seat").mouseout(function()
    {
        $('.username').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $(".free").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        window.location='?page=event/seatplan&action=pick&seat='+id;
    });
});
```

This is the jQuery code I have right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should be able to add your ypos to the scroll position of the page,

Change this line:

```
    $('#seat_'+id).css({"left":(x+30)+"px","top":(y+10)+"px"});
```

To:

```
    $('#seat_'+id).css({"left":(x+30)+"px","top":(y+10)+$(document).scrollTop()+"px"});
```

Comment: Sorry, Try using jquery position() instead of offset() this will then get the position relative to the chairs rather than the document